# Hidding custom List from gallery

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is there any way we can hide the custom list in a sharepoint gallery.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify - to stop people creating custom lists or to stop an existing custom list from being added to a page (web part gallery)?

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the comment. I want to stop an existing custom list from being added to a page. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, the only thing you can do is to set the list permissions so the users do not have access to the list, this is not what you want, right?